# Plot against dummy variables and grouped values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

This is some values of the table I have

```
   country  colour ...
1    Spain   red
2    USA     blue
3    Greece  green
4    Italy   white
5    USA     red
6    USA     blue
7    Spain   red
```

I want to be able to group the countries together and plot it where the country is in the x axis and the total number of 'colours' is calculated for each country. For example, country USA has 2 blues and 1 red, Spain has 2 reds etc. I want this in a bar chart form. I would like this to be done using either matplotlib or seaborn.

I would assume I would have to use dummy variables for the 'colours' column but I'm not sure how to plot against a grouped column and dummy variables.

Much appreciated if you could show and explain the process. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want stacked bars where a country has multiple colors, or side-by-side?

Comment: I would like them side by side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['country'], df['colour']).plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: WOW that is slick, this deserves a ton of upvotes

Comment: I was hoping to use matplotlib or seaborn. But anyway, is there a way to increase the figure size?

Comment: Pandas' `plot` uses matplotlib backend by default. You can pass `figsize=(10,6)` to `bar`. You can also create an matplotlib axis instance with `fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))` and pass to `bar` instead: `.plot.bar(ax=ax)`. Then you can modify `ax` to your heart's content.